# Can I use a resource over CORS without exposing the contents of that resource?

Tags: javascript, css, cors, web-development-server

Lets say that there is a CSS file on another domain I would like to access via CORS.

If I own the server supplying the CSS file, would it be possible to allow domains to fetch the CSS file and apply it to their page, while hiding the actual content of the CSS file/not exposing the code of the CSS file?

Comment: As a general rule, if you want the browser to be able to use something you're going to need to be okay with users being able to see the thing, too.

Comment: If a browser can use it, anyone can see it - not sure how the two paragraphs in the question are related

Answer (score 1):

> would it be possible to allow domains to fetch the CSS file and apply it to their page

You would normally be able to load a CSS file from other origins, without specifying CORS headers.

> while hiding the actual content of the CSS file/not exposing the code of the CSS file?

Depends what you mean. They wouldn't be able to read the file as text unless you set CORS headers. They would however be able to inspect the styles being applied to elements by on the page via JavaScript.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you're saying that by default JS and HTML files are only accessible by same origin calls, whereas CSS files are generally open to the public?

Would there be a way to protect these CSS files from the public using CORS?

What header would you use to expose the CSS file text publicly?

Comment: @SamSebree Typically you can load JS, CSS, HTML, images, etc cross-origin normally. You can't directly access their data via JavaScript though.

Comment: Would it be possible to host an image resource, and expose that image resource via CORS but hide its metadata such as its resolution?

Comment: @SamSebree If you can load the image you can easily find the display width/height cross-origin.

Comment: Are all these same principles true even in the case of a CSS file that is being hosted on a server and exposed via CORS, but isnt being applied to a publicly accessible web page?

Answer (score 0):

CSS runs on the **front-end**. As such, all CSS code running on a website (including CSS externally referenced via a `<link>` tag) is always **public** on a website. There is **no** way to hide CSS code (other than obfuscation, which would be fairly pointless).

CORS requests are made through JavaScript, which also operates client-side. As such, it is not possible to make a CORS request without that endpoint being exposed -- you could simply monitor the network trace to find out which endpoints are being hit, and what data is being passed to them.

Comment: is this true even in the case of a CSS file that is being hosted on a server and exposed via CORS, but isnt being applied to an accessible web page?